# Access context_dict within view

Tags: python, django

I am running the following query in Django to pass into a template

```
release_list = Releases.objects.filter(id=release_id).values('all_artists','label_no_country','id','title','genre')
context_dict['releases'] = release_list
```

I would then like to pass the `genre` data into another query within the view, e.g.

```
genre_list = Releases.objects.filter(genre=genre).values()
context_dict['genre_list'] = genre_list
```

How do I access the `genre` data from the first query?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking here. It's also not clear why you are using `filter` (and calling the result a plural) when only one object can match on ID. And you are definitely following an anti-pattern by using `values()` rather than passing the actual Release objects around.

Comment: Would be interested to find out more information about this sentence if you can give it? "And you are definitely following an anti-pattern by using values() rather than passing the actual Release objects around." Thanks

Comment: @Franco Added a little note at bottom of answer on how you can objects around instead of pulling values

Comment: Thanks @bakkal, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thing is

```
release_list = Releases.objects.filter(...).values('genre', ...)
```

Will behave like a list of objects with the keys you asked for so you can get *many* `genre` values, not *one*

If that's what you want then

```
for release in release_list:
    genre = release['genre']
    genre_list = Releases.objects.filter(genre=genre).values()
```

Or you can pull all the `genre` values from it

```
genres = [release['genre'] for release in release_list]
```

Then you can e.g. use it like this

```
genre_list = Releases.objects.filter(genre__in=genres)
```

Or you can pass the objects instead of values, that can work like this:

```
release = Releases.objects.get(...)
SomeModel.objects.filter(genre=release.genre)
```

Comment: genre_list = Releases.objects.filter(genre__in=genres) works perfectly (there is only ever going to be one genre). Thanks!